# Is there a way to access an attribute of an object that is a variable (dynamic) without using the getattr() function?

Tags: python, oop, dynamic, getattr, hasattr

I am writing a function which takes in an object of a class, e.g. Transaction, that has two attributes "date1" and "date2", which in turn are both classes that have three attributes "day", "month", and "year".I will pass this function an object of the class Transaction as well as whether I am analyzing "date1" or "date2". So the function will look something like:

```
def analyzeTransaction(txObject, date='date1'): 
    txObject.{date}.year()
```

Where `{date}` can either can referring to the date1 or date2 member depending on argument passed.

I know how to do this using getattr(), but I was hoping for a more elegant solution since I find using getattr() everywhere to be clunky.

Comment: Usually, if you find yourself wanting to dynamically choose which attribute of an object to access, you should rethink whether attributes were the right design choice in the first place.

Comment: Pass the object you want to call the method on, instead of its name.

Comment: `txObject.date1.year if date == 'date1' else txObject.date2.year` Not sure that's any better...

Comment: Why does this function take an object and an attribute name, instead of just taking the attribute value directly? `analyzeTransaction(tx.date1)` instead of `analyzeTransaction(tx, 'date1')`?

Comment: `date1` and `date2` should also probably be merged into a single list/tuple-valued attribute that you can index.

Comment: Depending on your class design, you may be able to use `txObject.__dict__` directly.

Comment: "since I find using getattr() everywhere to be clunky" because what you are doing - passing a string around that corresponds to an attribute that you want to access, is clunky. There is no better solution

Comment: For a note, I don't have any control over the class design. I have to work with what I have for now so to speak. Passing the object with its attribute sounds like the best choice here.

Comment: ANY TIME you find yourself using variables like `xxx1`, `xxx2`, `xxx3`, etc; they should all be replaced by a list or a dict.  A list of two dates would work fine here.

Comment: @TimRoberts The members actually are completely different. I just used something called "Date1", "Date2" as an example. This is a scientific computing application. But what you said makes complete sense.